# Determine Chrysler 3L engine model

Tags: engine, part-identification, chrysler

I am about to acquire an engine from a seller and I am having issues identifying what sort of engine it is exactly because I am getting conflicting information. On the top engine cover it says "CHRYSLER 3 Liter V6" and it also has the numbers 4439 (small) 835 (bold) as well as the engine built sticker saying "7 date 308".

Now I have been looking for 3L V6 engines from Chrysler and it insists on showing me a 3L diesel engine, however the one I am looking at is verifiably a gasoline engine. I thought maybe the 3L is not exactly 3L, however other engines from Chrysler mention the exact displacement (i.e the 3.6L engine saying 3.6 Litre V6).

I have attached an image of the top of the engine (I cant attach more images as I dont own them) below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out that this is a Mitsubishi [6G72](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_6G7_engine#6G72) engine made for Chrysler used in a Chrysler Plymouth (probably late 80s).